# Can you use the Bitly API to get all Bitly links that start with a certain value?

Tags: bitly

Let's say I have a Bitly link that I know beings with *bit.ly/mystery01* and I wanted to get all existing Bitly links that begin that way. Is there a call or method I can use to make that happen or is it not doable? I'm doubtful since the bit.ly link in question is not linked to my own account.

I'm new to using the Bitly API so I'm not sure what to check. I've been playing around with Retrieve Custom Bitlink mostly.